# SendGrid using string replacement with template_id

Tags: string, templates, str-replace, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I try to send a single Email via SendGrid API v3 with curl call.

I created a template and reference on it. In this template i placed some vars to be replace. Mails will be send successfully, but without it's string replacement.

There are the datastructure I sent. What do I wrong?

> {
>         "template_id": "d-1074861686174fbfac02e25381e02e32",
>         "personalizations": [
>           {
>             "to": [{"email": "test@test.de"}],
>             "sub": 
>               {
>                   "%USERNAME%": ["Hans"],
>                   "%DATE%": ["25.12.1988"],
>                   "%DAYS%": ["58"],
>               },
>           },
>         ],
>         "from": {
>           "email": "service@test.de",
>           "name": "Kundenservice"
>         },
>         "reply_to": {
>           "email": "support@test.de",
>           "name": "Kundenservice"
>         }
>       }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables that you want to replace in your template should be in curly braces

> {{ email }}

The thing is that now the substitution key changed to dynamic_template_data

```
 {
   "from":{
      "email":"example@.sendgrid.net"
   },
   "personalizations":[
      {
         "to":[
            {
               "email":"example@sendgrid.net"
            }
         ],
         "dynamic_template_data":{
            "name":"Sample Name",
            "city":"Place",
            "state":"CO"
          }
      }
   ],
   "template_id":"[template_id]"
}
```

Try this example and let me know if it works for you :)

There is also official documentation where it is explained very clear the entire sending process 
[How to send an email with Dynamic Transactional Templates](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/)